# Where are the Windows Registry locations of Google Chrome and Firefox when we set "block third party cookies" on browser?

Tags: registry

Where do Google Chrome and Firefox store there **registry** values when we set "**block third party cookies**" on browsers

1. **Chrome** (chrome://settings/content/cookies) and
2. **Firefox** (about:preferences#privacy)?

I'm trying to handle for option "block third party cookies" on browser Chrome and Firefox by editing there corresponding values in registry.
However, I cannot find the location of registry entry which handle for "block third party cookies"

I searched on the internet and I found some directions for this:

- For Chrome: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
- For Firefox: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Mozilla\lockedpref]

But I cannot find these directories on my PC and another PC, I also reinstall Chrome and Firefox with the newest version.

However, I can find and handle for the registry value of IE and Edge:

- For IE: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]
- For Edge: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main

Could you please tell me where are the locations of them on Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

They are not in the registry.  Organization policies still are however.

In *about:config*

network.cookie.alwaysAcceptSessionCookies = false
Disables acceptance of session cookies.

network.cookie.cookieBehavior
Disable cookies.
0 = All cookies are allowed. (Default)
1 = Only cookies from the originating server are allowed. (block third party cookies)
2 = No cookies are allowed.
3 = Third-party cookies are allowed only if that site has stored cookies already from a previous visit

network.cookie.lifetimePolicy
cookies are deleted at the end of the session
0 = The cookie's lifetime is supplied by the server. (Default)
1 = The user is prompted for the cookie's lifetime.
2 = The cookie expires at the end of the session (when the browser closes).
3 = The cookie lasts for the number of days specified by network.cookie.lifetime.days.